# Oracle Apex - Links in report row that gets a value from the row and uses it to generate another report on a different page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Oracle Apex 5.1

I have a report (Report A) that has a table of values generated from a SQL query.
How do I get a link column to get a value (e.g. employee_ID) of the current row  then send that value to another page that has a report (Report B) that is generated using the value from report A.

New to Apex and a lot of the guide or tutorials seem very convoluted for something that seems like quite a standard thing.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty basic thing and there are many examples of it online.

The simplest way is to create a `column link` (in attributes) which links to your target page containing report B.  On the page containing report B have a `hidden item` (e.g. employee_id) and in your link use the `set items` area to set `PX_employee_id` to value `#employee_id#`.  Then on report B have a `where clause` - `where employee_id = :PX_EMPLOYEE_ID` (replace X with the relevant page number).